# Reduce Time complexity of the following program

Tags: time, time-complexity, reduce

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Special_Pairs{

private static Scanner scan;


public static void main(String [] args) {
    byte t;
    int n;
    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    t=scan.nextByte();
    int[] a=new int[100000];
    while(t>0)
    {
        int i,j,count=0;
        n=scan.nextInt();
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=scan.nextInt();
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(((a[i]&a[j])==0)||((a[j]&a[i])==0))
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    t--;
    System.out.println(count);
    }       
}
}
```

**Help me reduce time complexity of this program**

## Question :

You have been given an integer array A on size N. You must report the number of ordered pairs `(i,j)` such that `A[i] & A[j]=0`.
Here `&` denotes the `BITWISE AND` `(i,j)` and `(j,i)` are considered different.

**Input:** First line contains T-Number of Test cases. First line of each test contains N. Next line contains N integers - the i'th integer A[i].

**Output:** Output the number of such pairs for each test case.

**Constraints:** T ≤ 10;     N ≤ 100000;      A[i] ≤ 1000000

Sample Input(Plaintext Link)

`1
5
41 47 34 40 29`

Sample Output(Plaintext Link)

`2`

**Explanation:** These are the required pairs `(3 5)` `(5 3)`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, this is not a code writing/homework solving service, show some effort. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest three optimization for this. I have modified the code as well.

1. You need not to always start from 0 for each iteration of outer loop. The second loop can start from `current+1` of the first loop. So will not be comparing elements which you have already compared.
2. You don't need to check for both pairs `(i,j)` and `(j,i)`. If one is zero then other will always be zero.
3. You need not to initialize the array with fix size. You can always initialize it reading the value of `n`.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pairs {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t = scan.nextInt();
    while(t > 0) {
      t--;
      int count = 0;
      int n = scan.nextInt();
      int a[] = new int[n];
      for(int i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        a[i]=scan.nextInt();
      }
      for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j<n; j++) {
          if((a[i] & a[j])==0)
          {
            count += 2;
          }
        }
      }
      System.out.println(count);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 2. you don't need to test both `(a[i]&a[j])==0` and `(a[j]&a[i])==0`. Only one is enough. (oh, man, you edited faster than I typed my answer. hehe)

Answer (score 0):

If you are competing on a programming contest (like ICPC or something like this), maybe you shouldn't use `Scanner`. It's too slow for reading from the keyboard. I've already competed at ICPC, but I used to use C++. Maybe you should try `BufferedReader` instead of `Scanner`.