# Finding all pairs of numbers in an array whose bitwise and is 0

Tags: algorithm, bitwise-and

I recently came through a question , it was about counting all the pairs of numbers in an array whose bitwise & is 0.The complexity required was O(n) or O(nlog(n)) or less. The numbers were in range 1 to 1000000.

My approach was of writing every number in binary form and then for each bit of a number checking whether it is 0 or 1 , if bit is 1 I can take those numbers which have 0 at same position and if bit is 0 I can take any number as 0*(any number) = 0.But my time complexity is O(n^2) which will not pass.

Comment: please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32405490/2254048).

Comment: thats O(n^2) I need O(n) or O(nlog(n))

Comment: I am not sure, it is achievable in less then `O(n^2)`. We need to perform `bitwise &` for each number in array with all the other numbers in the array. The optimization here is, algorithm should not compute for a pair which has been already compared/computed. Such optimization are already in-place in the solution.

Comment: You could try a [Bitwise Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie#Bitwise_tries). The analysis is complicated though - its run time will be proportional to the number of matches. If your data set contains a lot of numbers with mostly 0 bits, it will run slower.

Comment: You don't mention `n` but as a parameter in dominating functions: please be explicit, including _reporting the number of pairs that give a 0 & result_ versus _counting_ them.

Answer (score 2):

I would build a *binary* tree from the given array so that each bit will define whether we go left or right in the tree. For a three bit number 101 it would be:

NODE--> (1) Right --> (0) Left --> (1) Right

(I don't know how to format here a binary try, it deletes all multiple space so I am sorry for such poor illustration)

So this will take O(n) (building the branches and creating new nodes is O(1)).

Then using a recursive method which will take one number (X) from the array, process its bits and walk on the tree, so that for each bit `k`:

```
IF (k == num_of_bits)
   Then print pair (X, current node value)
        Return

IF (left branch exists)
    Then take left branch with X[num_of_bits..k+1] // we go left anyway
//ELSE - 'else' here was a mistake
IF X[k] == 0  // if the bit is 0 we can go in both directions
    Then IF (right branch exists)
            Then take right branch with X[num_of_bits..k+1]
```

Now calculation of the complexity is a little tricky because the worst case seems to be that all the bits are 0 but then in the tree you will have only one branch...
It looks to me that the complexity of this is O(n*log(n)) - if I didn't overlook anything.

So in total it is O(n) + O(n*log(n)) => O(n*log(n))

Answer (score 1):

You can use the concept of tries to solve this problem.

**Insert in trie:** First, insert all the numbers in the trie tree. This tree will be a binary tree and and we will take the left child as 0 and right child as 1. If you want to insert 1 having binary representation 001, it will be as follows:

> Root->left(0)->left(0)->right(1)

If the path already exits, don't add new nodes again. In this case, only traverse the tree and add 0 0r 1 where the path doesn't exist. Every leaf node will also maintain the count of each number. So, the time complexity of the insertion will be O(n*log2(max)) because we are inserting n elements and each insertion takes the time equal to number of bits in maximum number of the array.

**Query in trie**: For each number in the array, compare the value of bits in the number n and the bits on the tree you made. Start with first bit of number.

> If the bit is zero, traverse to the right or left of tree and if the bit is 1,
>   traverse to the left of tree.

Do this for each bit of the number till you reach the nth bit. If you can't recah nth bit, return not possible. If you reach nth bit, return the count stored in leaf node.
Fore more detailed explanation, refer to this link below,

[Trie tree](https://threads-iiith.quora.com/Tutorial-on-Trie-and-example-problems)

Comment: @shiram, _If the bit is zero, traverse to the right or left of tree_. Don't you mean traverse to the left **and** (not or) right of tree? ie we'd have to traverse both subtrees since AND'ing with bit 0 would yield 0 in both cases, and so both subtrees may produce a pair. If so, query complexity would be O(2^(h+1)) where h is tree height or max number of bits used to represent our numbers... ie given a num==0, we'd have to visit every node in tree.

Answer (score 0):

you can y this bruteforce

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

class BitAnd {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
//  Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);             
    int t=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    while(t-->0){
        int n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int arr[]= new int[n];

        String s[]=br.readLine().split(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
            arr[i]=Integer.parseInt(s[i]);              
        }
        int c=0;            
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if((arr[i]&arr[j])==0)c++;                  
            }               
        }
        System.out.println(c*2);            
    }     
  }
}
```

Comment: This method is already suggested in the comments. [Link Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32405490/2254048)